# How to generate a random 5 digit long hex value in Java

Tags: java, integer, hex

I am creating a application in Java where I need to allocate a unique ID to an object. This unique ID must be 5 digits long and be a hexadecimal value.

To do this I was thinking either get the previous hex value and add 1 to it then convert back to hex using Integer.toHexString() but I want to be sure every time the hex value is 5 digits long.

Is there a simple way of just generating a 5 digit long hex value. This could then be checked against the other ID's to ensure it's unique (not very efficient but is readable atleast).

Any help or advice appreciated!

Comment: Is `0000a` a 5-digit long hex value? If so, then use `String.format("%05x", random.nextInt(0x100000))`.

Comment: How about you just add one as you said, but once you reach 0xFFFFF you "overflow" back to 0x00000 ?

Comment: *" I need to allocate a unique ID"* random values are no good as *unique ID*. They may repeat.